# Change the options of a field according to the roles of the admin (Sonata admin)

Tags: fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-3.3

I have two different roles for my dashboard admin : ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN and ROLE_SONATA_SUPER_ADMIN .

Both roles have almost the same functionality but there is a difference when adding a new user : If the admin has the role 'ROLE_SONATA_SUPER_ADMIN ' It can add other admin ,if not It only can add simple users .

For the moment I displayed the field 'type 'To choose the type of user to add :

```
            ->add('type',ChoiceType::class,array('label' => 'Type' ,
            'choices' => array('ADMIN' => 'admin',
                'CLIENT' => 'client',

            )))
```

How I can change the field type options according to the admin role .?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

```
   protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $user=$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();


    if($user->hasRole("ROLE_SONATA_SUPER_ADMIN ")){


        $cases = ['ADMIN' => 'admin', 'CANDIDAT' => 'candidat',

        ];

    }else{

        $cases = [ 'CANDIDAT' => 'candidat',
            'CLIENT' => 'client',
        ];
    }
```

And :

```
        $formMapper->add('type',ChoiceType::class,array('label' => 'Type' ,
            'choices' => $cases))
```